# Rails 5, Couldnt't find User without and ID . Can you pass an Object through a form?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, action

I'm trying to code the ability for a User to add a Skill (belongs to User, Technology and Level) to it's skillset.

I have a simple_for_for in skills/new.html.erb:

```
  <%= simple_form_for [ @user, @skill ] do |f| %>
    <p>Select Tech</p>
    <div>
      <%= f.collection_select :technology_id, @techs, :id, :name%>
    </div>
    <p>Select Level</p>
    <div>
      <%= f.collection_select :level_id, @levels, :id, :name%>
    </div>
    <%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-primary" %>
  <% end %>
```

**Skills Controller:** the New action is passing a list of Technology and Level objects to the simple_form_for so the options the user can select are a list of all Technologies and Levels (say, Tech: Ruby, Level: Junior).

```
class SkillsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  def index
    @skills = policy_scope(Skill)
  end

  def new
    @techs = Technology.all
    @levels = Level.all
    @skill = Skill.new
    @user = current_user
    authorize @skill
  end

  def create
    skill = Skill.new(skill_params)
    authorize skill
    if skill.save
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      render :action => "new", @user => params[:user_id], @skill => skill
    end
  end

  private

  def skill_params
    params.require(:skill).permit(:user_id, :technology_id, :level_id)
  end


end
```

I'm having a couple problems:

The else clause is not sending @user and @skill correctly to the form after it fails to save the new Skill, but I don't know if the syntax is correct.

Actual problem: Is it ok for the form to pass the technology and level id's associated to the option selected rather than the object itself? I've tried manually finding all the Skill components manually like this which renders a "Couldn't find User without and ID" error:

```
  def create
    skill = Skill.new()
    technology = Technology.find(skill_params[:technology_id])
    level = Level.find(skill_params[:level_id])
    user = User.find(skill_params[:user_id])
    skill.user = user
    skill.technology = technology
    skill.level = level
    authorize skill
    if skill.save
      redirect_to projects_path
    else
      render :action => "new", @user => user, @skill => skill
    end
  end

  private

  def skill_params
    params.require(:skill).permit(:technology_id, :level_id, :user_id)
  end
```

Comment: Please add request logs - To check the request params

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First make sure you have setup an association from user to skills which you can build new records off of:

```
class User
  has_many :skills
end
```

If you application just lets users add skills to their own account you should just fetch the current user from the session:

```
def create
  @skill = current_user.skills.new(skill_params)
  authorize @skill
  if @skill.save
    redirect_to projects_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

Note that this removes the need for nesting the form and route completely:

```
resources :skills
```

```
<%= simple_form_for @skill do |f| %>
  # ...
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 2):

In your create action you can set the `@user` and `@skill` before trying to create/save it and than you can just render new in the else clause:

```rb
def create
  @user = current_user
  @skill = Skill.new(skill_params)
  authorize @skill
  if @skill.save
    redirect_to projects_path
  else
    render :new
  end
end
```

And yes you can pass the ID's because the ID's is what will be saved in the DB.

The reason for the error Couldn't find a user without an id, is probably because the skill_params doesn't have the user_id. You get the user_id with the `current_user` helper method and not through the form.